# android: How to onclick a recyclerview item which contains a fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with different viewgroups in it.

I have a linearlayout as one of the item of the recyclerview which is used to insert a fragment into it, because recyclerview cannot take directly fragment view. My aim is after the recylcerview items are loaded, when i click on the (linear layout item) which contains fragment it should open a new activity. i tried the following, but its not working.

```
volleyinsidemapview.xml

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/mapFragmentContainer"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp" />


public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case MAP:
            View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.volleyinsidemapview, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new PersonViewHoldermap(v1);
            break;



public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        simhasize = this.udupiwhattoseearray.size();
        simhaviewtype = viewHolder.getItemViewType();
        switch (simhaviewtype) {
            case MAP:
                PersonViewHoldermap vh1 = (PersonViewHoldermap) viewHolder;
                Caitanyafragment caitanyafragment = new Caitanyafragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mContext.beginTransaction();
                bundle.putInt("id", id);
                caitanyafragment.setArguments(bundle);
                vh1.frm.setId(mapids[i]);

                fragmentTransaction.add(mapids[i], caitanyafragment, maptags[i]).commit();

                vh1.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent m = new Intent(v.getContext(), CaitanyaMapview.class);
                        m.putExtra("id", id);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(m);
                        ((Activity) context).finish();
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                break;
```

Comment: Setting clicking event is not working at all, or working at some places?

Comment: its not working at all. My fragment consists of map. It zooms the map. instead of going to another activity

Comment: Because the map is taking the touch event, you need to disable the touch event of map.

Comment: Why don't you place a layout over the map, I think it will work.

Comment: thats what i was doing. In linearlayout, i have added mapfragment

Comment: i am saying place a layout over mapview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97539/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-nigam-patro).